# having trouble with dynamic segments in emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js

This should be simple to do. I just can't pass the value of the input to the product-details view. I'm trying to create a unique template page for each item added to the list. Clicking the 'details' link should take the user to the unique page. I understand how dynamic segments works, I'm just getting stuck somewhere.

Thanks!

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/midivu/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your link to helper you need to pass the parameter in...

```
{{#link-to 'details' name class="add-item-button"}}
```

Example.. 
If you imagine link-to as a function then **in your case** it would be

```
linkTo(route, segment, etc...)
```

But imagine it this way just to understand the adding parameter...

**To fix your Details Route**

```
App.DetailsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return userList.findBy('name', params.itemName); // assuming you want to find the details by it's name
    }
});
```

This is because you did not create a data store. You are using a global variable as your data store, therefore, you must get it from the global.

Comment: adding the parameter in there gives me the following error.

Error while processing route: details Cannot read property 'find' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at App.DetailsRoute.Ember.Route.extend.model

Comment: That is because of you Details Route, The Link To Helper now works as expected though... Let me take a look at the Details Route and see whats going on. I suspect that `this.store` is undefined in your model hook

Comment: i was missing the ember data script, but now it says:

Error while processing route: details undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function.

what am i missing?